# How to use eqnarray in R markdown for both html and pdf output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I can't work out how to use eqnarray to create equations in R markdown such that I can create both html and pdf output. This R markdown works for `output_format='html_document'` but not `output_format='pdf_document'`

```
My LaTeX equations
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& x \\
B &=& y
\end{eqnarray}
$$
```

For pdf output it gives this error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.81 \begin{eqnarray}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If I remove the `$$` then this R markdown works for pdf output but the equation is missing from the html output.

```
My LaTeX equations
\begin{eqnarray}
A &=& x \\
B &=& y
\end{eqnarray}
```

Am I missing something here? Is there some way to generate both pdf and html output from the same document?

Comment: Honestly I do not think that is possible because LaTeX equations are rendered in HTML by using [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org) and the `$$` identify piece of code that "activate" the mathjax plugin. Without that `$$` the code is just pure LaTeX and browsers do not know how to render.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. That seems a real shame for the R markdown formatting to limit the choice of output format.

Comment: Well... one idea I have could be to build a function that read into the YAML prefix of each file and set some `$$`s before and after equation environments if the output is set to `'html_document'`. But that's just an idea, honestly I don't even know where to start to code something like that.

Comment: I've got the same problem with simple markdown documents. `eqnarray` returns an error when trying to convert to pdf using `pandoc` but a correct output by converting to `html`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and found that while `eqnarray` has the problems mentioned above, in the context of R markdown and `knitr`, the `aligned` environment works for both PDF and HTML output.  Try this:

```
My LaTeX equations
\begin{aligned}
A &= x \\
B &= y
\end{aligned}
```

Note that there is only one `&` symbol here and that it's the alignment operator in the context for the `aligned` environment.  `aligned` works a little differently to `eqnarray` in that it will align at more than just one tab stop, so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

For Word output, this works:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
A &= x \\
B &= y
\end{aligned}
\]
```